# How to trigger an event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have this event handler, I need to fire this event pro grammatically in WPF application.
Problem could be related to access modifiers.
Any idea how to do it?

```
private void Monitor (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (App.monitor.IsPrinterReady() == false)
    {
        App.isPrintAllowed = false;               
    }
    else
    {
        App.isPrintAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define: at a specific time.

Comment: only once programmtically

Comment: you want it only once and that too programmatically then why not call it when your application loads.

Comment: Not sure I'm following your question; your event handler is by itself nothing more than a method (with a specific signature), so you can simply call it in code: `this.Monitor(null, EventArgs.Empty);`.

Comment: Extract the code out in some private method and call from your event handler and from wherever you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked ***how to raise the event***, this is how:

```
YourClassInstance.YourEvent(YourClassInstance, SomeEventArgsInstance);
```

Of course this works only if it's an event you declared yourself, in one of your own class. If not, then unless the said class's API allows it somehow you won't be able to do it like this.

You can still call the function that is bound to the event as others suggested, but I would do it differently:

```
private void MonitoringHandler (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Monitor();
}

private void Monitor()
{
    App.isPrintAllowed = App.monitor.IsPrinterReady();               
}
```

Here the `MonitoringHandler` method is the one you'll want to bind to your event (whatever it is). Afterwards, if you need to programmatically call the same action triggered by your event, just call the `Monitor` function as you would any other method, without any parameters:

```
YourClass.Monitor();
```

That design is cleaner and makes much more sense IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just call it like a method:

```
Monitor (null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it like you would any other function/method:
`Monitor(null, null)`

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to have an OnMonitor method which can be used to fire off the event programmatically. This will then call all subscribers to that event.

Also note that Monitor will be null if you have no subscribers to that event, so you need to check whether or not it is null first to avoid risk of throwing an exception.

```
private void OnMonitor()
{
    if (Monitor != null)
    {
        Monitor(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the common OnWhatever pattern implies a protected, overridable method that accepts a EventArgs (or derived) typed parameter. That's still good advice though.